# ObservableCollection и абстрактный лист

Tags: c#, wpf

Допустим есть какой либо абстрактный класс, который имеет в себе основную реализацию. Ну как принято во многих статьях или книгах - `AbstractBox`.

От этой абстрактной коробки наследуется три класса

```
AbstractBox
|_BigBox
|_SmallBox
|_MediumBox
```

Предположим что у нас есть `List<AbstractBox> container = new List<AbstractBox>();` И я могу **гарантировать** что в данной коллекции **лежат и будут лежать** на момент использования **объекты одного класса**.

Есть `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="ListHolder">
</DataGrid>
```

Если в него попытаться положить данный лист, он сформирует колонки **только** под поля абстрактного класса. Вопрос, как мне использовать данный датагрид для такого листа? Опять таки : в нем могут лежать объекты только одного класса, чтобы не создавать коллизий байндингов датагрида.

Comment: Тогда доступны будут только члены абстрактного класса, что тут не понятного? Хотите конкретный класс - делайте конкретный лист и датагрид

Comment: @Bulson а методы как можно это обойти?

Comment: Вы сначала создаете иерархию, а потом желаете ее обойти! В чем тогда смысл? Создать проблему, а потом бороться с ней?